# Truncate text with width = 100%

Tags: css, flexbox, truncate

I have HTML

```css
.container {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
.first {
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.second {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 0;
}

.second div {
  overflow: hidden; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">123</div>
  <div class="second">
    <h3>Header</h3>
    <div>A very long text A very long text A very long text A very long text A very long text A very long text A very long text A very long text A very long text A very long text A very long text A very long text </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The main problem here is that the size of the .SECOND div gets wider and it doesn't truncate the text

You are able to see it here

https://jsbin.com/sesamayuji/edit?html,output
If I set the width of the `.second div` to 300px, it will work, but I need 100%

[image]

Comment: Can you use javascript?

Answer (score -2):

```
.second {width: 0;}
```

This is the answer

Comment: No one can understand your answer

Comment: You need to explain your answer.

Comment: British humour?